# Why i got net.rim.device.api.system.ControlledAccessException in blackberry os 5?

Tags: blackberry, device

I am using **ToDo List** in my app.It is working fine in simulator but it gives me error in blackberry Strom 9550  like this :

> net.rim.device.api.system.ControlledAccessException

Plz help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the app permissions? The simulator gives access to most by default, actual devices do not.

I've also ran into a problem in the past where you might get past it by redeploying a couple times (while the app is running), and occasionally had to uninstall and reboot.

Comment: i have imported the sqlLite demo project from blackberry samples @jprofitt.In simulator it displays screen about database not initialized while in device it displays this exception. i had uninstalled the app and installed it again after restarting the device.Still the exception occurs.Pls help me