# Blackberry global popup

Tags: blackberry

I'm trying to popup a global dialog from a background thread that I started from an alternate entry point.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyApp theApp = new MyApp();  
    if (args != null && args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("test")) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) {
                        UiEngine ui = Ui.getUiEngine();
                        Screen screen = new Dialog(Dialog.D_OK, "Test", Dialog.OK,
                                                   Bitmap.getPredefinedBitmap(Bitmap.EXCLAMATION),
                                                   Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
                        ui.pushGlobalScreen(screen, 1, UiEngine.GLOBAL_MODAL);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                }
            }
        }).start();
    } else {
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    }
}
```

I tried so many variations to make it work but it's still not showing up. I tried

synchronizing `Application.getEventLock()`, I also tried
`UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater`,
`UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait`. I even tried `synchronizing the eventlock` first before calling the `invokeLater` (which I think is redundant, but I still tried...). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: have you tried `ui.pushGlobalScreen(screen, 1, UiEngine.GLOBAL_QUEUE);`

Comment: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-Background-Application/ta-p/445226 also check this link

Comment: yes, I tried using the GLOBAL_QUEUE

Comment: I'm actually already extending the UiApplication since the application I'm doing is a GUI app, but it does have some threads that should start in an alternate entry point. Based on the sample code, does it mean that there's a difference if I start my thread inside the contructor vs. the alternate entry point?

Comment: it turned out the I did have to start the worker thread in the constructor for the global dialog to show up, although I don't know why. Does anyone know the explanation?

Comment: do you have an alternate entry point in your application ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okk i am giving you a sample demo ....

First of all edit the **BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml** click on `Application Tab`
In ApplicationArgument write `alternate` and check Auto Run on start up 
Click on `Alternate Entry Points` click on add and write in the title `BackgroundApp`

Make a class which will extend Application class rather than UiApplication class like this way

```
 
import net.rim.device.api.system.Alert;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Application;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Screen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Ui;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiEngine;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;


public class BackGroundApp extends Application {
//  this class is used for the background processing .....

     public void startBackgroundThread()
        {
            new Thread(){
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(60000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }




                        synchronized (getEventLock()) {

                            //with this UiEngine pushGlobal dialogs

                            //whenever with the app in background

                            UiEngine ui = Ui.getUiEngine();
                            Screen screen = new Dialog(Dialog.D_OK, "You have updates!",
                                    Dialog.OK, Bitmap
                                            .getPredefinedBitmap(Bitmap.EXCLAMATION),
                                    Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
                            ui.pushGlobalScreen(screen, 1, UiEngine.GLOBAL_QUEUE);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }

}
```

Make a class which will extend UiApplication class like this way

```
public class GuiTest extends UiApplication {
    static Timer t; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         if(args.length>0&&"alternate".equals(args[0])){

                            BackGroundApp app = new BackGroundApp();
                            app.startBackgroundThread();
                            app.enterEventDispatcher();

            }

         else{
             GuiTest test = new GuiTest();          
             test.enterEventDispatcher();
         }
    }
    public GuiTest(){
        Myscreen screeMyscreen = new Myscreen();
        pushScreen(screeMyscreen);
    }

}
```

Now make a class MyScreen and add all your Ui in it .... and push the screen

```
public class Myscreen extends MainScreen {



    public Myscreen(){
    CreateGui();
    }

    public void CreateGui(){
       // Your Ui goes here .......
     }

}
```

run the sample you will see after one minute a dialog will appear on your screen no matter if you are in the application or out side of it. Thanks may be this might be help full.

Comment: Okay I followed your example above and it worked great... at least until I tested it on the 9900 OS 7.0.0.440... What's weird is it's working fine on 9700 (simulator and device) and it's also working on the 9900 simulator. Whenever I call synchronized(getEventLock()), I get a AccessControlException. I have two Listeners calling the method of the BackgroundApp that shows the global dialog, what's weird is when the SMSListener is calling it, everything works fine, but when the EmailListener is calling it...

Comment: , I get an AccessControlException whenever it passes the synchronized(getEventLock()), and this only happens on the device, it works fine on the simulator.

Comment: Sorry, it was ControlledAccessException

Comment: I think your application permissions are not set to `"Allow"` access to email. And [see this thread on **SO**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435220/why-i-got-net-rim-device-api-system-controlledaccessexception-in-blackberry-os-5)

Comment: it's able to send and listen for emails, the only problem is that whenever I put the synchronized(getEventLock()) block (I even tried just leaving the block itself and removed the contents), it throws that exception. But aside from that it works fine, and like I said, what's weird is it's only happening on the 9900 device, I have no problems on 9900 simulator and the 9700 too (both device and simulator).

Comment: anyway, I just decided to do workaround and create an inner Runnable class that will run an infinite loop (like in your example) and the thread will wait() if there are no updates and will be notify() if there are updates.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments, you've been very helpful.